# Where does a "render" in the controller action method go to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am looking at a code that in one of its controllers, in one of its action methods first it calls a service to get a JSON, puts it in a `json_data` varaible and as for the next and last command says `render json: json_data`

But I can't understand what happens after that? what is the next line of code that gets run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`render json: json_data` is in fact the final statement executed in the function. After it's executed, the function is automatically exited.

Whenever something is "rendered" in a Rails controller, whether it's an action, a template, or otherwise, the rendering is the final executed statement in the controller function.

In the case of the `render json: json_data`, `ActionController` will render out the passed argument, `json_data`, by whatever method is defined. In this case, it's JSON, so Rails renders the contents of `json_data` to the browser in JSON format, complete with respective headers. To contrast, if the statement was `render text: json_data`, ActionController would send the contents of `json_data` to the browser as text.

You may want to check out the [canonical Rails guide's documentation on `render`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render), which provides several examples of it can be invoked within the context of a controller action.

Comment: yes I know..I mean what does it execute after that? to whom and where does it deliver this json_data ?

Comment: hmm ok so render json passes its json data TO THE BROWSER, cool...I now understood this part...but the guy is using D3,JS to draw CHARTS and the DATA for those CHARTS are these json_data...so what happens after we are sending it to browser?

Comment: What happens after the data is sent to the browser has nothing to do with Rails, FYI. In the example you illustrated, assuming that your JSON is valid, the browser will parse the data into a form usable by whatever you're trying to pass the data to.